# Plutchik's emotions from negative to positive

Tags: emotion, sentiment-analysis

I'm trying to order Plutchik's emotions model from the most negative to the most positive.

These are the emotions in alphabetical order:

```
anger, anticipation, disgust, fear, joy, sadness, surprise, trust
```

I didn't find anything online regarding this. Can someone help me?

Comment: I think they are context specific. E.g Disgust, you may assume to be negative but it's evolution & purpose is to keep you alive (avoiding certain foods). Depends on the perspective.

Comment: Why do you think they should have an ordering from negative to positive?

Comment: More generally, it isn't clear that emotions have this dimension at all.  For example, check out this great post: https://psychology.stackexchange.com/a/9500/7001, where the same emotion can be very negative or very positive or anything else inbetween, depending on context.

Comment: @BryanKrause , because of this picture: https://positivepsychology.com/wp-content/uploads/geneva-emotion-wheel.png , but my problem is that some emotions (e.g. `fear` and `disgust`) have the same level of "negative".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Negative to positive suggests a linear scale between negative and positive.  The literature does not seem to support such a one dimensional scale.

There is a two-dimensional taxonomy that has the personality descriptor 'negative' in cell (-2,-2) and positive in (2,2), which suggests a diagonal line on the two-dimensional plane that best represents negative to positive (Mobbs, 2020).

The words are scored and sorted in accordance with the atlas as follows.

[image]

Mobbs AED (2020) An atlas of personality, emotion and behaviour. PLoS ONE 15(1): e0227877. https://doi.org/10.1371/journal.pone.0227877